# Stylus eraser not distinguished from pen tip

Tags: wacom, stylus

I have an HP TC4400 convertible tablet, which has a stylus with eraser.

```
$ xsetwacom list
Serial Wacom Tablet stylus              id: 11  type: STYLUS    
Serial Wacom Tablet eraser              id: 13  type: ERASER
```

The stylus and eraser worked properly for a long time, but recently there has been some strange behaviour that I don't understand.

When I run xournal with its "Eraser tip" option as I used to (which is supposed to cause the eraser of the stylus to be treated differently from the other end), then both ends of the pen are interpreted as the eraser.

I tried to deal with this by using xsetwacom to map the eraser to something different from the stylus. However, while the following line does make touching the eraser to the screen like a right click, it also makes the other end of the pen act like a right click as well:

```
xsetwacom set "Serial Wacom Tablet eraser" button 1 3
```

I would have expected that setting properties of the eraser would not alter the stylus at all.

Any ideas of what is going on and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same. I don't know if this is the right way to fix. I appended:

```
Option "Button3" "2"
```

to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf`, and then

```
xsetwacom set "Serial Wacom Tablet eraser" button 1 3
```