# Assigning eraser to a pen button on Wacom Tablet

Tags: tablet, wacom

I'm trying to configure my Wacom CTL-472 tablet so that I can use one of the buttons on the pen as an eraser. Now this tablet doesn't "officially" come with an eraser, however on Windows using the "Wacom Tablet Properties" app it is possible to assign one of the button on the pen to act as an eraser as shown in the screenshot below:
[image: Wacom Tablet Properties on Windows]

On Linux, I've been unable to find a way to make this work. Using `xsetwacom --list devices`, I get the following:

> Wacom One by Wacom S Pen stylus id: 9 type:STYLUS
> Wacom One by Wacom S Pen eraser id: 9 type:ERASER

I've tried running various combinationg `xsetwacom set "Wacom One by Wacom S Pen stylus" Button X Y` (playing with different values of X and Y, but that didn't work (the suggestion here [Stylus eraser not distinguished from pen tip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263329/stylus-eraser-not-distinguished-from-pen-tip) didn't work either). It seems that it's possible to assign a keyboard shortcut or a wheel up/down to one of the buttons (for example using the KDE's Graphic Tablet utility), but I couldn't find a way so that applications recognize the buttons as an eraser. Is there a workaround this?

Comment: I assume that you checked the button settings in the Wacom settings panel, and didn't find ERASE. Does your Wacom have buttons along the top? If so, see if the "Map Buttons" feature will work for you. Otherwise, can you select the eraser tool in your app?

Comment: Yes, there is no erase option. Upon investigating, that this is a limitation that cannot be circumvented since the wacom drivers for Linux (unlike in Windows) do not support assigning buttons to the ERASE function (unless the pen has builtin support for an eraser). See here https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/issues/209